# Tomcat logs are being written to syslog instead to the application log in Spring Boot and Log4j

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, log4j

It's a Spring Boot application with Log4j for logging.
All logs from `org.apache.catalina.*` are being sent to syslog, and it includes also uncaught exceptions.

Our app uses Log4j (v1) since it uses legacy code dependencies that use Log4j.

Spring Boot version is `1.5.2.RELEASE`.

I believe that with correct set-up, also tomcat logs will be written to the same file that is configured in the `log4j.xml`, but i couldn't find any answer to that problem.

`pom.xml` (relevant parts):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Logging -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

`log4j.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} [%t] %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- File appender -->
    <appender name="logFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/tmp/myappname.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="BufferedIO" value="false" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} [%t] %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="logFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: It is no good idea to write your logfiles in `/tmp`

Comment: That's the dev log4j.xml + that's not related to the question

Answer (score 0):

Could you try excluding it in the actuator artifact?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Based on your comment:

If I understood correctly, the application is logging fine, it's the servlet container the logging to syslog when exceptions bubble up, isn't?

Could you also try adding:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and / or passing where log4j config file is located:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=<path to file>
```

If these don't work, the only thing I could think of is that you are using `Spring Boot` 1.5.x doesn't get along with `Log4j` and likely requires to uplift it to `Log4j2`

Comment: It didn't solve the issue. Calling an endpoint that throws NPE logs it to syslog

Comment: Didn't work, however i use SB 1.5 and this is probably the issue. I'm sure there is a workaround but still couldn't find one.